# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError when retrieving data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

The following code i written works only when the localStorage value is an integer or when the value consists of only digits. Im fairly new with Javascript so it's possible that the answer is right in front of me..

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    localStorage.setItem('test', '12345');
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
    localStorage.setItem('john', 'doe');
    localStorage.setItem('carl', 14);

            var name, content;
            for (var key in localStorage) {
                $("#test").append('<button onclick="senddata('+localStorage[key]+')">'+key+'</button>');
            }

    function senddata(content) {
    $.post("processor.php",
       {text: content},
       function(response){
           console.log(response);
       }
          );
    }
</script>
```

When pressing buttons generated by the code the following appears in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: doe is not defined
14
12345
14
```

processor.php

```
if (isset($_POST['text']))
    die($_POST['text']);
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$("#test").append('<button onclick="senddata('+localStorage[key]+')">'+key+'</button>');
```

to

```
$("#test").append('<button onclick="senddata(\''+localStorage[key]+'\')">'+key+'</button>');
```

otherwise it will try to send the undefined variable `bar` (`sendata(bar)`) instead of the string `'bar'` (`sendata('bar')`).

Answer (score 0):

Numeric literals are written bare. Eg `123`

But string literals always need single or double quotes. Eg. `'foo'` or `"foo"`

Check that you are quoting the string literals as needed.

Also, have you tried debugging? Step through your script to see exactly what is and is not happening. You will also probably be given an error at some point.